# Why is the list of spaces of my Confluence wiki empty?

Tags: confluence-rest-api

I have a Confluence wiki with over 1000 spaces. I try to retrieve the list  of spaces of my Confluence wiki using the curl query:

```
curl -D -u user:password -X GET \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://[hostname]/rest/api/space
```

It returns an empty list of spaces:

```
{"results":[],"start":0,"limit":25,"size":0,
 "_links":{"self":https://[hostname]/rest/api/space,
 "e":https://[hostname],"context":""}}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/api-group-space/#api-wiki-rest-api-space-get states:

> Note, the returned list will only contain spaces that the current user has permission to view.

That was indeed a permission issue: the account used to make the curl query had no permission for any spaces.